# Time class generating OutOfMemory Error

Tags: java, timer, out-of-memory

I am using the Time class and creating it of 20 tps, but I am getting below error.

```
 Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-9" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
        at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:137)
        at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:106)
        at mcarbon.ucip.SheduleInMemRemove.<init>(SheduleInMemRemove.java:22)
        at mcarbon.ucip.XML_RPC_UCIP_DEBIT_CREDIT.run(XML_RPC_UCIP_DEBIT_CREDIT.java:229)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Code:-

```
class SheduleInMemRemove{
            Timer timer;
        Config cfg;
          String key;

           public SheduleInMemRemove(String key,int seconds,Config cfg,String MSG,String IP,String PORT,boolean isResponse)
           {
                this.key=key;
                this.cfg=cfg;
                 LoggerWR.logger.info("[IN URL] [inside SheduleInMemRemove constructor][going to sleep to IN memory key["+key+"] [wake up after "+seconds+" seconds] [MSG]["+MSG+"] [isResponse]["+isResponse+"]");
                cfg.addInMem(key,IP,PORT,MSG,isResponse);
                //LoggerWR.logger.info("[IN URL] [Going to shedule]");
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new WakeUpInTask(),seconds*1000);
                //LoggerWR.logger.info("[IN URL] [Done]");
           }
                class WakeUpInTask extends TimerTask
                {
                public void run() {
                //System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
                LoggerWR.logger.info("[IN URL] [Inside the SheduleInMemRemove class going to remove the key]["+key+"] ["+cfg.removeInMem(key)+"]");
                 //cfg.removeInMem(key);
                    timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
                }
        }
    }
```

pls help

Comment: It says it is **OutOfMemory**. Please increase the JVM heap size.

Comment: Hi, I am running via java -Xms128m -Xmx512m. pls suggest how much memory is enough, I have only 4 GB RAM in system. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to know how much is enough is to increase memory until you don't get the error anymore. Nobody can tell how much is needed without having your full program and doing exactly that.

Comment: Wait a minute, this message comes from a **native** method of the  `Thread` class. How many instances of `SheduleInMemRemove` (and thus, of `Timer`/`Thread`) are you creating?

Comment: I am creating 200 instance of SheduleInMemRemove and same for Timer, after 15 min removing that data from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Each new thread is going to require a big chunk of memory to use for its call stack. Apparently, you're launching more threads than you have memory for.

If you're creating a large number of timers, you should consider using [a ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead.

Comment: I am storing some data in hashmap for 15 mins, then we need to remove this data, so I am using Timer class here, how can I use ScheduledExecutorService here. I need some triger after 15 min.