# HashMap remove after a fix time

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I want to remove the value from hashmap after 1/2 an hour of putting it.
pls suggest.

Ex:- if I am putting some data in HashMap at 10:30 am, then I want to remove it at 11.00 am.

Comment: Any attempt with code?

Comment: I am using timer class where I set the key, and removing this key when run method invoke, but due to high load I am getting below error. Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-9" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:597)
        at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:137)
        at java.util.Timer.<init>(Timer.java:106)

Comment: Suggest you put comment in answer itself

Comment: @Patel, pls elaborate..

Comment: Tejas means "question" when he says "answer".

Comment: Do you want to remove it or make it irretrievable after 1/2 hour? The latter is much easier - you can remove the value when someone wants to retrieve it, and you don't need a separate clean thread or timer function.

Comment: I don't want to iterate it,the Timer class is a simple solution of my problem but for every key I am creating a new object of Timer class and it taking huge memory chunk so its throwing outof memory error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer class in java. For a demo refer this site .http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm

Or else, create a hashMap and add an object as key and the time you add as value.

Then have a method called as delete which takes the time in milliseconds. Have a count down timer function and if the timer reaches zero, it should return true.

Within the if condition in delete method, check if the IF condition is true, if it is true, set a variable initialTime which is currentTime - milliseconds that user passed to the delete method.

then iterate hashmap which matches with initialTime and delete it.

This is the rough algo

```
public void delete(Time inMilliSeconds){
     if(countDownTimer()){
         initialTime = CurrentTimeInstance - inMilliSeconds;
         //Iterate HashMap and delete all values which is equal to initialTime;
     }
}

public boolean countDownTimer(inMilliSeconds){
     //Timer that reduces to 00:00:00. After running down to zero return true.

}
```

Comment: @Siva the same thing I am doing but after putting aprox 1000 values it throwing above Exception, Thanks.

Comment: Code Link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844057/time-class-generating-outofmemory-error

Comment: @Siva I don't want to iterate HashMap everyTime it will take high CPU, actually the problem is for every key I am creating a new object of Timer class and it taking huge memory chunk so its throwing outof memory error.